# MHSMM package R input data format with multiple variables

Tags: r

my problem is similar to the question as following[the problem of R-input Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682619/mhsmm-package-in-r-input-format/29035288#29035288)

I have tried the above code in the above link and revised some part to suit my data. my data is like follow [image: 4 variables, 397 * 4]
I want my data can be created as a data frame with 4 variable vectors. The code what I have revised is

```
formatMhsmm <- function(data){
 nb.sequences = nrow(data)
 nb.variables = ncol(data)
 data_df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
 # iterate over these in loops
 rows <- 1: nb.sequences     
 # build vector with id value
id = numeric(length = nb.sequences)
for( i in rows)
{
  id[i] = data_df[i,2]  
 }
 # build vector with time value
 time = numeric (length = nb.sequences)
 for( i in rows)
 {
  time[i] = data_df[i,3]  
  }
# build vector with observation values
 sequences = numeric(length = nb.sequences)
 for(i in rows)
{
  sequences[i] = data_df[i, 4]
  }
 data.df = data.frame(id,time,sequences)
# creation of hsmm data object need for training
 N <- as.numeric(table(data.df$id))
 train <- list(x = data.df$sequences, N = N)
 class(train) <- "hsmm.data"
 return(train)
}
library(mhsmm)
dataset <- read.csv("location.csv", header = TRUE)
train <- formatMhsmm(dataset)
print(train)
```

The output observation is not the data of 4th col, it's a list of (4, 8, 12,...,396, 1, 1, ..., 56, 192,...,6550, 68, NA, NA,...) It has picked up 1/4 data of each col. Why it is like this?

Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply count yout observations by Id, and create the hsmm.data object directly? Supposing yout dataframe is called "data", we have:

```
N <- as.numeric(table(data$id))
train <- list(x=data$location, N = N)
class(train) <- "hsmm.data"
```

Extracted from http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i04/paper